# iRIS Xe Graphics Card and Mint 20.02

Tags: linux-mint, intel-graphics

I have a new HP laptop with the iRIS Xe graphics card and Linux Mint 20.02, but am not able to get the screen resolution to change from a default value. I'm wondering how to do that and if it's related to the graphics card.

I have tried the following (all at once):

1. Booting in EFI mode and changing quiet splash to nomodeset in Linux Mint options
2. Updating the kernel to 5.11 (see below)
3. For another issue (screen flickering), I have also done this:

   sudo nano /etc/default/grub

add nomodeset" after "quiet splash

```
sudo update-grub
```

I do recall seeing "AMD64" when digging around in some config files.

Here are some system and hardware details:

```
System:    Kernel: 5.11.0-25-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: MATE 1.24.0 Distro: Linux Mint 20.2 Uma 
           base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: HP product: HP Laptop 14-dq2xxx v: N/A serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: HP model: 87FD v: 57.16 serial: <filter> UEFI: AMI v: F.10 date: 04/15/2021 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 5.0 Wh condition: 42.4/41.0 Wh (103%) model: HP Primary status: Discharging 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: 11th Gen Intel Core i5-1135G7 bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Tiger Lake rev: 1 
           L2 cache: 8192 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 38707 
           Speed: 1725 MHz min/max: 400/4200 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1800 2: 1852 3: 1832 4: 1800 5: 3005 6: 1781 
           7: 2615 8: 2237 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: N/A bus ID: 0000:00:02.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: fbdev unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~77Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 12.0.0 256 bits) v: 4.5 Mesa 21.0.3 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: sof-audio-pci bus ID: 0000:00:1f.3 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.11.0-25-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 3000 bus ID: 0000:00:14.3 
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 16.16 GiB (6.8%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Western Digital model: PC SN530 SDBPNPZ-256G-1006 size: 238.47 GiB 
RAID:      Hardware-1: Intel Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller driver: vmd v: 0.6 bus ID: 0000:00:0e.0 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 233.24 GiB used: 16.16 GiB (6.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p2 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 52.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 237 Uptime: 21m Memory: 11.35 GiB used: 1.94 GiB (17.1%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 9.3.0 Shell: bash v: 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some ideas here: Squeezing More Performance Out Of Intel Tiger Lake Xe Graphics By Using Mesa Git 21.04 
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=TGL-Xe-Graphics-More-Mesa-Git
Gen12 Xe Graphics might not be working out-of-the-box depending upon your kernel. 
Install OEM kernel
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2002372&sid=7eab49285b06a0cda51c4ed7ace61615#p2002372

Comment: I don't see any mention of whether you've installed a kernel mode display driver for this graphics card.  This is also mentioned in the article that @oldfred posted in their comment.

Comment: What is the "default resolution" and what are you trying to change it to? The screen on your laptop model is limited to 1920x1080 regardless of what the graphics card can do. I'm running dual 2560x1440 external monitors just fine on the 5.11 kernel with Xe.

Comment: It seems that the lack of options for screen resolution and fuzzy lines on the screen indicate that the graphics card driver is not "working". When the computer is restarted, this happens. The solution for now is to reinstall Ubuntu 21.04 each time. I'm hoping the new release on 10/14(?) resolves this.